# mysql log system

Tags: mysql, logging

I have set log = "c:/xampp/mysql.log" in my.ini file for mysql. but it just logs the connections and there is no query there. what shiuld i do next ? 
I also used general_log =1 and it didnt work either.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL v5.1.29 or later, you should specify the desired location with the [`general_log_file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file) system variable.

If you're using MySQL v5.5, you should also ensure that [`log_output`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output) is set to `FILE`.